# Boundary conditions in method of images for an infinite grounded plane

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, boundary-conditions

We have a charge $q$ situated above a grounded infinite plane at some distance. This $q$ will induce some charge on the plane. But I've read that one of the boundary conditions for potential is that the potential that we need to find just above the plane, goes to zero at infinity. How is this true as we have an **infinite** plane of induced charge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do have an infinite plane of induced charge but a finite charge is induced(unlike what you probably assumed). Also, the induced charge do not have a uniform charge density.